# How to extract digits from a String and transform them into an Integer

Tags: ruby

How to remove space between 2 numbers ?
I have a String `"1 026 personnes aiment ça"` and I would like to get only `1026` (as Integer)

My attempt:

```
text = "1 026 personnes aiment ça"
# => "1 026 personnes aiment ça"
z = text.split(' ').first
# => "1 026"
z.to_i
# => 1
z.strip
# => "1 026"
z.class
# => String
```

Comment: It heavily depends on the format the strings you can receive. Do you have more examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#gsub` method can replace all non-digit characters in the String and then you can transform it into an Integer with `#to_i`:

```
"1 026 personnes aiment ça".gsub(/\D/, "").to_i
#~> 1026
```

Comment: Take care though: `"1 234 personnes. 56 chiens".gsub(/\D/, "").to_i #=> 123456`

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks for the heads up, but it's a bit unclear what the expected output should be for the example you've mentioned. Sebastian did ask for more examples in the comments but OP didn't provide any unfortunately. This answer was accepted as it is so I'm not sure if altering it would be the correct way to go.

Comment: I totally understand. I just wanted to note that it could lead to unexpected behaviour. You don't need to change anything, especially since OP's question lacks information. Also: `"NoNumber".gsub(/\D/, "").to_i #=> 0`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this it`s work for me

```
(?<=\d) +(?=\d+(?:\s|$))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"1 026 personnes aiment ça".gsub(' ', '').to_i
=> 1026
```

Comment: In such case better using `tr`.

Comment: thanks @SebastianPalma , will sure take care  , Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you can do:

```
text = "1 026 personnes aiment ça"
z = text.split(' ')
z = z[0]+ z[1]
z.to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions (keep in mind this can get slow if you are doing a lot of iterations)

```
'1 026 personnes aiment ça'.match(/\d{1,3} \d{1,3}/)
                           .to_s
                           .tr(' ','')
                           .to_i
# => 3123
```

This would:

- match the first 2 groups of 3 or fewer numbers
- convert it to a string (MatchData only has method to convert the result to a string or an array)
- replace spaces with an empty string
- convert the string to an integer

  '1 026 personnes aiment ça'.match(/\d{1,3} \d{1,3}/)

Keeping in mind that this will silently fail, I would change the regex depending on what kind of text you are expecting.

For example; if you expect the first character of the string to be a digit,  I would add `^` (indicates start of line).

```
'1 026 personnes aiment ça'.match(/^\d{1,3} \d{1,3}/)
                           .to_s
                           .tr(' ','')
                           .to_i
```